# Saving Aspose.Slides.Presentation prevents file from being opened

Tags: aspose

I am attempting to modify a Presentation file with Aspose.Slides.

```
var fileMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
await fileMemoryStream.WriteAsync(file.FileData, 0, file.FileData.Length);

Presentation pres = new Presentation(fileMemoryStream);
IDocumentProperties pptProperties = pres.DocumentProperties;
pptProperties.Title = "test";

pres.Save(fileMemoryStream, Aspose.Slides.Export.SaveFormat.Pptx);

fileMemoryStream.Position = 0;
fileData = fileMemoryStream.ToArray();
var contentType = fileProperties.MimeTypes.ContainsKey(file.Extension) ? fileProperties.MimeTypes[file.Extension]: "application"+file.Extension.Replace(".", "/");
var fileConvert = File(fileData, contentType, exemplarFile.DownloadName + file.Extension);
```

Ff I comment out the pres.Save line, the file works.  If I don't, it won't open and I'm left with the message below.

> "Powerpoint found a problem with content in *path*.pptx. Powerpoint can attempt to repair the presentation."

If I comment out *pptProperties.Title = "test";*, it does not work.  setting the fileMemoryStream to zero at the beginning does not work.  I must be missing a step in the Aspose process, or the memorystream process.  Any ideas?

Note: the file being tested is a pptx file and the Mimetype is correct

> application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what was happening, but saving the pres to a new MemoryStream instead of the current one worked.

If anyone has an idea as to why this is feel free to post, but this is what solved this.